# Bootstrap dropdown button not working when published to Heroku (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I have already searched around StackOverflow and have been trying for a while to solve this, but none of them works.

Although I reordered the line in application.js and set precompile in production.rb to "true", it still does not work when pushed to Heroku. Locally, however, it is wokring fine.

Please take a look at my project file --> https://github.com/star747jet/sbadmin2.1.git

I'm using ruby 2.2.4 and rails 4.2.6 on Ubuntu 14.04. Thanks

Update:
I reorder the line in application.js to be

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap
//= require bootstrap_sb_admin_base_v2
```

and publish to Heroku

Heroku logs after publish (I think there is no error here)

```
2016-05-02T04:41:14.505700+00:00 heroku[api]: Enable Logplex by tanapon.aree@gmail.com
2016-05-02T04:41:14.505700+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v2 created by tanapon.aree@gmail.com
2016-05-02T04:44:19.410522+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v3 created by tanapon.aree@gmail.com
2016-05-02T04:44:19.410522+00:00 heroku[api]: Set LANG, RACK_ENV, RAILS_ENV, RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES, SECRET_KEY_BASE config vars by tanapon.aree@gmail.com
2016-05-02T04:44:20.107984+00:00 heroku[api]: Attach DATABASE (@ref:postgresql-contoured-49654) by tanapon.aree@gmail.com
2016-05-02T04:44:20.107984+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v4 created by tanapon.aree@gmail.com
2016-05-02T04:44:20.562428+00:00 heroku[api]: Scale to web=1 by tanapon.aree@gmail.com
2016-05-02T04:44:20.562897+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 58726b3 by tanapon.aree@gmail.com
2016-05-02T04:44:20.562897+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v5 created by tanapon.aree@gmail.com
2016-05-02T04:44:20.939703+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2016-05-02T04:44:20.939708+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2016-05-02T04:44:23.584547+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 18464 -e production`
2016-05-02T04:44:27.214026+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-05-02 04:44:27] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2016-05-02T04:44:27.214047+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-05-02 04:44:27] INFO  ruby 2.2.4 (2015-12-16) [x86_64-linux]
2016-05-02T04:44:27.214304+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-05-02 04:44:27] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=3 port=18464
2016-05-02T04:44:27.741557+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2016-05-02T04:48:33.746996+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by tanapon.aree@gmail.com
2016-05-02T04:48:37.688192+00:00 heroku[run.6174]: Awaiting client
2016-05-02T04:48:37.768392+00:00 heroku[run.6174]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2016-05-02T04:48:37.919170+00:00 heroku[run.6174]: State changed from starting to up
2016-05-02T04:48:45.675830+00:00 heroku[run.6174]: Process exited with status 0
2016-05-02T04:48:45.696153+00:00 heroku[run.6174]: State changed from up to complete
```

Heroku logs after do "heroku run rake assets:precompile
" and reload the webpage.(all six line below begin with red colr timestamp)

```
2016-05-02T04:53:40.727583+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=seastest.herokuapp.com request_id=2940cf64-16c8-48ea-ae87-7113bd76315f fwd="58.11.221.244" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=10ms status=302 bytes=994
2016-05-02T04:53:41.143685+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/users/sign_in" host=seastest.herokuapp.com request_id=0907e800-2894-4c56-b674-8c3760b89794 fwd="58.11.221.244" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=10ms status=200 bytes=6010
2016-05-02T04:53:41.517598+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-7a9d5ae8202aacde4376876c4b8f86770fdb15d3cb2f361e5504142bbe04c9b1.css" host=seastest.herokuapp.com request_id=fcc95013-635b-4b8f-a680-f1c2f4ed3077 fwd="58.11.221.244" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=200 bytes=31608
2016-05-02T04:53:42.124687+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-eb16686e7fa82584bf03646c97a53b5a11d7aaa29cc889d8a18ab556c25b2ee8.js" host=seastest.herokuapp.com request_id=8581be8f-a249-49ec-b59a-f243a9fb7622 fwd="58.11.221.244" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=11ms status=200 bytes=141559
2016-05-02T04:53:44.312552+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/images/banner.png" host=seastest.herokuapp.com request_id=ec07c53f-a46b-45a1-8492-4b00d55e3be9 fwd="58.11.221.244" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=18ms status=200 bytes=263984
2016-05-02T04:53:44.505642+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/fontawesome-webfont-v=4.2.0.woff" host=seastest.herokuapp.com request_id=ea63ce17-70d8-412b-9ff0-e2cc806431a4 fwd="58.11.221.244" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=175ms status=200 bytes=65845
```

Comment: which gem or how do other people imoirt bootstrap and its them like sbadmin2 into the project?

Comment: Any javascript error in console ? All assets is correctly compiled ?

Comment: Sorry for late reply....Please take a look at heroku logs above.

Comment: No error when you going on the app URL ?

Comment: there is no error show on the browser during load the url(it just show the page with all drop-down button not working),but there is error on heroku logs as I show above.(the last 6 lines)

Comment: Try to debug locally in production environment